# Non-negative solution of $\partial_t H = \Delta H + |A|^2(H-1)$

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

This question is from a transformation of mean curvature flow. I want to find a precise initial conditions to keep $H \ge 1$ or $H\le 1$ under this flow.

Consider PDE  on closed smooth manifold $M^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$
$$
\partial_t H  = \Delta H + |A|^2(H-1)
$$
$H$ is mean curvature , $A$ is second fundamental form.  We always assume $H \ge 0$. Obviously, if the $H\ge 1$ at every point when $t=0$. Then, it will be $H\ge 1$ for $t > 0$.  For $ H\le 1$ , we have liking result.

But even for convex manifold, the initial condition , $H\ge 1$ or $H\le 1$ at everywhere, is too rough. Whether $\int _{M_0} (H-1) d\mu \ge 1$ can keep $H\ge 1$ for $t> T$? $M_0$ is the initial manifold, $T$ is a enough big number. In fact, I think it is not right. If so, what initial condition is suitable for keeping $H\ge 1$ or $H\le 1$ ?

Comment: What is your evolution equation?

Comment: @JohnMa  It is $\partial_t F =-(H -1)\nu$

Comment: @JohnMa  I am trying to write  a paper  about  $\partial_t F =-(H -1)\nu$ liking Huisken's MCF and volume preserving MCF.  In fact , there is little new things , just imitate Huisken's method.  But I really need write something to finish my PhD.  How do you think about this way?  Thanks.

Comment: I have the following suggestions: (1): Thinks clearly before working that if this new evolutaion equations is not trivial: are they just under some transformation that of MCF or some combination with $F_t = -v$? (2) the natural guess is that under some condition the flow converges to the constant mean curvature surface, if you can find some such condition it seems to be a good result.

Comment: (3) Take a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1133.pdf), where they show that the initial immersion does not have to be $C^2$ close to sphere in order to get convergence to sphere. Is there any similar analogue?