# Application or meaning of $\partial_t F = -(H - \gamma )\nu$

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

About two month ago, I try to study this flow
$$
\partial_t F = -(H - \gamma )\nu
$$
where $F$ is position vector , $H$ is mean curvature , $\gamma$ is positive constant, $\nu$ is normal vector. It is a slight modification of mean curvature flow.

As I talk  in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381976/non-negative-solution-of-partial-t-h-delta-h-a2h-1), most motivation of me  is for finishing my PhD. Now, most of paper has been finished. But today my teacher think it has little  meaning or application and easy to be refused.  I  really don't know what meaning or application it has. What should I do ?

Comment: [Something like this](http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2802&context=eispapers) has been proposed to model fire front propagation, although with variable $\gamma$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Thanks very much. Seemly, it is what I want.

Comment: So what have you proved exactly? Is that under some conditions the flow converges to CMC surfaces?

Comment: @JohnMa  I  proved the surfaces have two different converge result for different initial condition, but the initial condition is rough. I get stuck in the non-convex initial condition, in fact, I don't know  how to normalize this flow , as what I ask in this [question][https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462849/normalizing-a-geometric-flow-liking-mean-curvature-flow].  The general way of  normalize will creat a coupling equations, I am trying to deal it.